# Pulling Data from 1 DataContext to use in another's Method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been trying to convert this SQL statement to a LINQ one and am having trouble with the fact that part of the info returned is in a Seperate Database(Datacontext) from the rest.  I am pretty sure this can be overcome however I seem to be failing at accomplishing this or finding examples of previous successful attempts.

Can someone offer some guidance on what I do to overcome that hurdle?  Thanks

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, cp.EnrollmentID, cp.EnrollmentDate, cp.DisenrollmentDate
FROM [Connect].dbo.tblPerson AS p
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c.ClientID, c.EnrollmentID, c.EnrollmentDate, c.DisenrollmentDate
    FROM [CMO].dbo.tblCMOEnrollment AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [CMO].dbo.tblWorkerHistory AS wh
        ON c.EnrollmentID = wh.EnrollmentID
            INNER JOIN [CMO].dbo.tblStaffExtended AS se
            ON wh.Worker = se.StaffID
    WHERE (wh.EndDate IS NULL OR wh.EndDate >= getdate())
    AND wh.Worker = --WorkerGUID Param here
) AS cp
ON p.PersonID = cp.ClientID

ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

I have asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3876402/46724) before as was told I would need to create a View in order to accomplish this.  Is that still true or was it ever?

Answer (score 1):

I use LINQPad to do a lot of my LINQ to SQL.  One of the features it allows is the use of multiple data contexts for one query.

for instance here is some code that I wrote in LINQPad

```
from template in RateTemplates
where
   template.Policies.Any(p => 
      Staging_history.Changes.Any(c => 
         (c.Policies.Any(cp => cp.PolicyID == p.PolicyID) || 
         c.PolicyFees.Any(cpf => cpf.PolicyID == p.PolicyID) || 
         c.PolicyOptions.Any(cpo => cpo.PolicyID == p.PolicyID)) &&
         c.ChangeTime > new DateTime(2012, 1, 11)
      )
   )
select new
{
   TemplateID  = template.ID,
   UserID      = template.UserID,
   PropertyIDs = template.Properties.Select(ppty => ppty.PropertyID)
}
```

The table "RateTemplates" is a part of my first Data Context *(With LINQPad you do not have to define the first data context in your code it is just assumed, but if you do this is C# you would need to specifically say which context to use etc)*. "Staging_history" is the second Data Context and I am using the table "Changes" from this one.

LINQ to SQL will do all sorts of magic in the background and the resulting SQL that gets executed is ...

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2012-01-11 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ID] AS [TemplateID], [t0].[UserID], [t1].[PropertyID], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Property] AS [t7]
    WHERE [t7].[RateTemplateID] = [t0].[ID]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [RateTemplate] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Property] AS [t1] ON [t1].[RateTemplateID] = [t0].[ID]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Policy] AS [t2]
    WHERE (EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [staging_history].[dbo].[Change] AS [t3]
        WHERE ((EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [staging_history].[dbo].[Policy] AS [t4]
            WHERE ([t4].[PolicyID] = [t2].[PolicyID]) AND ([t4].[ChangeID] = [t3].[ID])
            )) OR (EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [staging_history].[dbo].[PolicyFee] AS [t5]
            WHERE ([t5].[PolicyID] = [t2].[PolicyID]) AND ([t5].[ChangeID] = [t3].[ID])
            )) OR (EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [staging_history].[dbo].[PolicyOption] AS [t6]
            WHERE ([t6].[PolicyID] = [t2].[PolicyID]) AND ([t6].[ChangeID] = [t3].[ID])
            ))) AND ([t3].[ChangeTime] > @p0)
        )) AND ([t2].[RateTemplateID] = [t0].[ID])
    )
ORDER BY [t0].[ID], [t1].[PropertyID]
```

So it looks like you would just need to load up one data context for each database that you want to use and then just build up a LINQ query that makes use of both data contexts in one linq statement, like I have up above.

Hopefully this helps you out and gets you the results you are wanting without having to go creating views for each cross context queries that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (I'm no guru on linqtosql) was the same, that it wasn't possible without using a view/sproc.

However, a quick search, found [this on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/b3e88f82-be90-4cd7-8a8d-024b0482df3c) with a workaround. Quote from Damien's answer on there:

> 2.Add one of the tables to the other data context (Copy the DBML over and prefix the name attribute with the name of the database, e.g.
>   database2.dbo.MyTable)